# ¿Cómo puedo conectar mi botón en html?

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Tengo un botón en un index en HTML, y estoy trabajando con spring boot.

Ya tengo el código listo en spring boot pero quiero conectarlo a html y no sé cómo. Quisiera saber ¿cómo podría hacerlo?

El botón es un botón de descarga de archivos previamente subidos.

El botón de subir y adjuntar archivos ya lo tengo configurado y sin problema lo adjunta pero no sé cómo hacer que se descarguen esos archivos con un botón después

**Código en Spring Boot y HTML**

```
**Configuración de GetMapping en SpringBoot**
 
/Config btn descargar
    @GetMapping("/transaction/diagrama-flujo/{idSolicitud}")
    public void descargarDiagramaFlujo(@PathVariable Long idSolicitud, HttpServletResponse response){
    
       // DOCUMENTOS_DETALLE_PLAN_PAGO_ENTITY solicitud= FetchData.getDocumentoDetallePlanPagoById(idSolicitud);
       SOLICITUD_ENTITY solicitud=fetchData.getSolicitud(idSolicitud);
       if(solicitud!=null){
        File documentoDiagrama = new File(solicitud.getPathDiagrama());

        if(documentoDiagrama.exists()){
            String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(documentoDiagrama.getName());
            if (mimeType == null) {
                //unknown mimetype so set the mimetype to application/octet-stream
                mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
            }
            response.setContentType(mimeType);
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename="+ documentoDiagrama.getName());
            response.setContentLength((int) documentoDiagrama.length());

            try {
                InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(documentoDiagrama));
                FileCopyUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());                    
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }else{
        response.setStatus(404);
    }
}
```

---

**Botón en html**

```html
<!--Boton para descargar los diagramas-->
<a class="btn btn-success d-none" id="modal_btn_diagrama">
    Descargar <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Primero que nada, lo que compartiste como "Botón en HTML" no es un boton, es un link. Qué significa `quiero conectarlo a html` a qué te refieres con conectar?. Por favor lee [example] y [ask] para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: Con conectar me refería a como hacer que ese botón (o enlace en este caso, estoy probando con ambas opciones), funcione con el código en Spring Boot. Ya hice eso previamente con el botón para adjuntarlo pero lo que hice en ese botón no me funciona en este

Comment: Bien, podrías compartir el código de lo que hiciste con el otro botón? Así tenemos una referencia de lo que estás intentando hacer. Te recomiendo nuevamente que leas [example]